# How to calculate this limit of a function defined in pieces in x=4?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, limsup-and-liminf

I am sure that the result is indeterminate, but I am missing the foundation.

Let f:R->R , such that

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 &  & \\ x , x<0
 &  & \\ 3-x , 0 \leqslant x <4
 &  &  \\ 2 ,x \geqslant 4
\end{matrix}\right.$$

that we can say about
$$ \lim x\rightarrow 4 f(x)$$

Comment: Do you know how to compute $\lim_{x\to4^-}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to4^+}f(x)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Compute $\lim{x\to 4^{-}} f(x)$ and $\lim{x\to 4^{+}} f(x).$ If they are equal then $\lim_{x\to 4} f(x)$ will be exist.

Comment: ok thank ,but it will be written a)does not exist b)indeterminate c)infinite ?

Comment: $-1\ne 2$, therefore does not exist.

Comment: @herbsteinberg, you are right.